# how to pass data from one controller to another without showing on url and it should works on refresh the page

Tags: angularjs

Good Morning. I have a question how to pass multiple params from one controller to another contorller without using location.path and also the id values won't show on url.when i using service setter and getter , id values were gone when refreshed the page.can you please some idea how to stop showing the param values on url and pass to next controller in Angular js 1.x

Comment: Save the params in local storage

Comment: is there any way to pass data without using local storage and session storage ?

Comment: The problem will be when you refresh the page no data will be save in client site unless you use coockie or local storage. You can try to save the data in your server side i think its better approach for you.

Comment: Whenever you are sharing the data between 2 controllers always use services. Passing in params is not a good option when your data size is big.

Comment: Yes sharma . That's what I was trying. But service not working when refreshing the page . Data has gone in service